# Can i access Argument that a BackgroundWorker was started with when it completes?

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

When i start a `BackgroundWorker` i can pass an arbitrary *argument*:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(someStuff);
```

The intended use is that this arbitrary argument is supplied to the `DoWork` method:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   Object someStuff = e.Argument;
   ...
}
```

Now i would like that same argument back during the *Complete* callback:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Object myStuff = e.Argument;
    ...
}
```

Except that that **is no** `e.Argument`.

There *is* a `UserState`:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Object myStuff = e.UserState;
    ...
}
```

But it's a known bug that `UserState` is never set, or settable, to anything.

So what's a good workaround?

### Bonus Reading

- [How do you set the UserState in the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310166/how-do-you-set-the-userstate-in-the-runworkercompletedeventargs-object)

Comment: Your BackgroundWorker could put it in the Result?

Comment: Dammit. i kept googling for an answer, and came across this question, "*Hey, this is exactly what i want! +1*"  "You can't vote for your own posts."  "*Oh, ok :(*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the argument in an array of object along with the actual result. from inside the doWork handler.

```
        BackgroundWorker bgw = null;

    void main()
    {
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string otherResult = "Some Work Done";
        e.Result = new Object[2] {e.Argument, otherResult};
    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //writes the argument;
        Console.WriteLine(((object[])e.Result)[0]);
    }
```

Comment: i guess, strictly speaking, Blorgbeard beat you to it. But he didn't phrase it as an answer, and didn't include sample code. +1 and accepted

Comment: When I'm too lazy to type an answer, I type a comment and upvote the eventual answer :P